# sublime text 2 project sidebar stopped reacting on new files

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

So I am using Sublime Text 2 with several plug-ins (but not too many: BracketHiglighter, CSS snippets, FileDiffs, Gist and Package Control).

Out of the blue the sidebar with file list of the project stopped reacting on file changes.
When I create a new one and save it to the folder, it does not appear in the sidebar at once, but only after Sublime restart, which is unacceptable.

Does anyone have an idea on this?

Comment: Don't know why the sidebar isn't updating, but you probably don't have to restart. Try refreshing the folders `Project -> Refresh Folders` or create a keybinding and set the command to `refresh_folder_list`

Comment: Thank you! Will try it later when I am at office.

Comment: @skuroda Refreshing folders helps, it is not bad actually. But the folders don't update themselves as it happened before.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa when saving the file just says 'Writing file' and that's all.

Comment: Try to create clean Sublime Text 2 installation and install add-ons one by one to see when it breaks

Comment: Thank you for reply, @MikkoOhtamaa. Yet I tried deactivating plugins one by one and it did not help.

Comment: That's why I said you do a clean Sublime Text 2 install and reinstall plugins one by one

Comment: Did you figure this out by chance? Happening to me as well, but only on one particular project...

Comment: Not yet, @agmcleod. Also happening on one particular project (which I already finished) ), and did not have time to reinstall Sublime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That project, where it appeared finished, and haven't occured on the new ones.
Suppose it could be caused by some low machine performance - for the large project.

**Update**

Excluding system/framework core folders also helps.

```
"folder_exclude_patterns": ["node_modules", ".svn", ".git", ".hg", "CVS"],
```

Can be done globally and in project **Folders** settings.

Comment: For node development I use `"folder_exclude_patterns": ["node_modules/*/node_modules/*/node_modules", ... .git etcetera]` to be able to browse first and second level dependencies yet hide dependencies on the third level and below.